# 2 billion increments in 2.3 Ghz cpu

Tags: performance, cpu, frequency, instructions

This simple code snippet output is in the range of 11 - 13 milli seconds. Now `assuming` for sake of question, that an increment of x is just a single instruction, the 2.3Ghz cpu of mind should take rougly a second to execute, since value of intMAX is close of 2 billion. Why is the answer in order of few milli's (11 - 13 millis) rather than in order of seconds (900 millis - 1100 millis) ??

```
    long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int x = 0;
    while (x < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        x++;
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time1);
```

Comment: Not knowledgeable in Java, but I'm suspecting dead variable elimination. Try printing the value of `x`. Otherwise maybe it has calculated that `x` will be `Integer.MAX_VALUE` without actually incrementing it.

Comment: @RamchandraApte printing x does not change the output

Comment: Can you add information about your Java JIT/interpreter/compiler?

Comment: cpu could be doing other stuff too. Also, jvm works differently from actual cpu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory - this can be optimized down to x=Integer.MAX_VALUE and then if x is not used after, completely removed

it is getting harder and harder to test how long things take since they get optimized out, especially if unused

try setting x to different start values and using x after the timer in a print or other calculation that leads to a print